# How to properly handle repeatedly served images on S3

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a web app kind of like canva so I have design images I need to store. Is the best way to store them on s3 just to manually upload each design, make the bucket public, and input the url to each image in my web app?

I ask this question because

1. I don't know if just making the bucket public is standard practice.
2. Since the user will be repeatedly loading the main page with all the designs, the images will be constantly reloading. That's why I say repeatedly in the title. Is there a way to better handle the images so it doesn't constantly request?

What I've tried- I've looked at the documentation, but honestly I do not like the AWS documentation. In my opinion it doesn't give clear answers to questions like these. I've looked for other stack overflow questions, and I could not find a lot clearly discussing this either.

Let me know if I'm not being clear on anything. Obviously I am not well versed in image storage or anything in that realm so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Its fine to make such buckets public with permissions like u can add domain specific permission and keep it public.
2. If you directly serving from S3, at some point it will cost u more. Provision cloudfront with S3 to serve images. AWS already provides [image handler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/), you can find in cloud formation templates